# Cron jobs not working in cPanel

Tags: cron

While using Cron Jobs I was encountered the below error.

`/bin/sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable`

Can anybody tell me what's this error and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

Restart your cron service. If still get error, view your log.